# Is it ok to delete iOS Files from my macbook pro?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, filesystem, storage, mobile-device-management

I have in my MacBook pro a folder called MyName iPhone. Which is taking up about 21gb of space.

It seems like a backup of the phone. It says last accessed: 2 years ago which happens to be when I go my MacBook pro.

**What happens if I delete this folder? Is it recommended? What will I lose? Will my phone's data be lost or unrecoverable?**

Comment: What is the location of the Folder? Where do you see it? In Finder or via some app such as iTunes or Music app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I got to it via the about my mac->storage->manage->iOS Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You may safely delete these files listed in iOS Installers as they are the last version of iOS you installed on your iDevice(s). They're used to restore your iDevice without needing a download if there has been no new update to iOS. If you delete these files and you later need to restore your iPhone, iTunes will update to the newest iOS version by uploading the appropriate installer file.

I manage my iPhone 8 & an iPad 6th Gen through iTunes and this is what I see. The top section are backups, and the bottom section the installer (.ipsw) files:

[image]